# Map Servers: anyplatfom (opensource or not) to embed into website to query with SQL for further breakdown

Tags: c#, php, javascript, asp.net, dictionary

I am looking for a mapserver, or a tool which can be embedded into the website.
where I want to be able to perform queries eg: 5 km around radius of nearest cities etc.
I have the data for it, in geo data format.
I want to know the best web applications available, or tools which can be embedded into website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can use the built in SQL 2008 geography data type (spacial data) and do simple calculations

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895266.aspx

But you must first find lat/lon of each location you are trying to find the distance to or from which you can use google api or others... Here is an example query.

```sql
select * from tableX where GeoFieldInDb.STDistance(geoLocation2) <= number
```